# problems acessing php files in wampserver

Tags: php, file, wampserver

I recently installed wampserver and thought I did everything correctly but not sure I did. My wampserver icon is green and I created a project in phpmyadmin.

When I type in `localhost` in my browser address bar, I can see the project listed on the wampserver page listed under my projects. I also created a php file under `c:/wamp/www/new document.php` but when I try to run a test to retrieve the php file I get an error:

> Not Found
>   The requested URL `/webapp/init.php` was not found on this server.
>   Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80

Can someone help me access this php file? I'm trying to follow a tutorial and can't get beyond this step.

Comment: If you can see the WAMPServer homepage when you enter `localhost` in the browser then Apache and PHP are working just fine as the homepage is a php script. What happens when you enter this url `localhost/new/document.php` does it run then?

Comment: If you asked for `new document.php` and were told the webserver could not find `init.php` did you not wonder why the file name changed? There's something in your code, your network config or your webserver config you've not told us about.

Answer (score 0):

That's better you do not use `spaces` in file names. Please try to replace any `spaces` in file names, with `underscores( _ )`.

Also according to the given error, you have maybe used one of these php functions:

```
include()
include_once()
require()
require_once()
```

fot the `init.php` file, with an address that does not exist. Please try to check the relative path to the file.

Comment: Agree about spaces not being good practice, but that would not result in the error message provided. A problem with the include path would result in a PHP file error, not an apache URL error.